# mercurial + Apache gives 403 error

Tags: apache, mercurial, http-status-code-403, hgweb

I have setup my repo at /home/adil/hg/sample-repo and want to serve it via httpd. I am following the tutorial at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#multiple and have created the hgweb.config file and have copied hgweb.cgi (renamed it to index.cgi) to /home/adil/web/mercurial/

My apache config (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) looks like this :

```
ScriptAlias /hg "/home/adil/web/mercurial/index.cgi"

<Directory "/home/adil/web/mercurial">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Options ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

index.cgi, hgweb.config and all the dirs upwards have world read permissions

http://localhost/hg gives a "403 Forbidden" error. WTF?

PS: Apache error log shows :
    [Sun Oct 17 06:45:38 2010] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] (13)Permission denied: access to /hg denied

Comment: What does the error.log file say? It might contain more detailed info about why access was denied

Comment: I updated my question with the error message. As above, just permission denied. It doesn't give any more info.

Comment: I will update the answer with some more ways to check Apache's user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Apache config expert by any means, but I was experiencing this error and managed to get rid of it.

Before I did, I was getting this error in my error_log: `client denied by server configuration: /Users/svn/Public/hg/hgwebdir.cgi`

This was my original config:

```
ScriptAlias /hg "/Users/svn/Public/hg/hgwebdir.cgi"
<Location /hg>
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Mercurial Repositories"
   AuthUserFile /Users/svn/Public/hg/auth
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I added some options:

```
ScriptAlias /hg "/Users/svn/Public/hg/hgwebdir.cgi"
<Location /hg>
  Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
  Options None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Mercurial Repositories"
  AuthUserFile /Users/svn/Public/hg/auth
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I tried Pablo's version too - one problem I experienced was that "ScriptAliasMatch ^/hg(.*)" was capturing the hg logo and stylesheets needed to render the browser repo explorer. I'm not sure if this even applies to `hgweb.cgi` because I don't use that one, but it was definitely an issue while using `hgwebdir.cgi`. Specifically: `script not found or unable to stat: /Users/svn/Public/hg/hgweb.cgilogo.png`

Answer (score 0):

Probably Apache's process owner does not have permissions to access `/home/adil/web/mercurial`.

Also, do check Apache's error log (usually located in `/var/log/httpd-error.log` or some place similar. It will give you extra information to debug your installation.

To check what's the user running Apache's process do:

```
$ ps aux | grep http
```

`ps` should show what's the user running Apache.

Also, in case it helps, here's the way I do it:

```
ScriptAliasMatch        ^/hg(.*)        /usr/local/share/mercurial/www/hgweb.cgi$1
<Directory /usr/local/share/mercurial/www>
  Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Options None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Pablo, it has read permissions on all the directories. How can i check of user 'apache' can access it?

Comment: Does it have permissions for the repositories as well? or just for the CGI script?